# What is the possible number of unique google meet codes?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

This is a sample google meet code: **kgk-imsy-era**
Any idea how many such unique codes can be there?

Given that a particular letter in the code may or may not repeat. If it repeats, we do not know how may times it'll repeat.

Is it something like
$$^{10}C_{x} \cdot 26^{x} \cdot ^{25}P_{(10-x)} + ^{26}P_{10}$$
where, ***x** = number of times a particular letter is repeated*

> **Few points to note:**
>
> - The codes are always composed of 10 letters (and no numbers)
> - The codes are case-insensitive
> - The hyphens in between are just used to separate the letters and are **not** a part of the code

Thanks!

Comment: all the letters do not repeat

Comment: @AmanKushwaha: Your response is appreciated, but since the question lacks context as such, it'd be better if you post a hint and not the answer.

Comment: @Billy: firstly, welcome to MathSE! Post all the restrictions by "editing" your post. There is an edit button below the post, above your name.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting used to it...

Comment: Hint: First choose the particular letter which gets repeated.Then, choose rest of the $10-x$ letters from the remaining $25$ alphabets. Then arrange the $10$ letters keeping in mind that some letters are repeated.

Comment: It is unclear from your post what the format of these codes is. Are the codes always the same length? What letters can be used? Are the minus signs always in the same place, or are they just like a letter and can occur anywhere and any number of times? If it is always 12 characters long and uses the 26 lower case letters and a minus sign as its character set, then there are $27^{12}$ possible codes.

Comment: Now that you've clarified the code format, is what you're asking for not simply $26^{10}$, 26 choices for each of the 10 characters in the code? The repeating or not is an overcomplication - each letter can simply be chosen separately without regard for the other letters.

Comment: When you say: "Given that a particular letter in the code may or may not repeat, if it repeats, we do not know how may times it'll repeat," are you implying that you are only counting codes where at most one letter is repeated? If so, this is perhaps the most important detail, so it should be emphasized, probably by listing it as a bullet with the other clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know about the procedure of google meeting codes , but i will write my answer according to given information by you.

We have two option such that a particular letter repeat or not repeat.

If it the particular letter does not repeat :

Firstly ,select this letter by $C(26,1)=26$ ways and select the rest by $C(25,9)$.After that arrange them by $P(10,10)$ .Then the answer is $$C(26,1) \times C(25,9) \times P(10,10)$$

If it the particular letter does  repeat :

Firstly ,select this letter by $C(26,1)=26$ ways .However , we do not know how many times it will repeat ,so we will use generating function to calculate the all possible arrangements of letters such that

Generating function for selected letter = $$ \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ..$$

$\color{red}{NOTE=}$ We started by $\frac{x^2}{2!}$ to avoid overcounting when the letter occurs only once

Generating function for the rest of  letters = $$1+ x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ..$$

So ,we should find the coefficient of $x^{10}$ and multiply it by $10!$ or find the coefficient of $\frac{x^{10}}{10!}$ in the expansion of $$\bigg( \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ..\bigg) \times \bigg(1+x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ..\bigg)^{25} $$

You can find the answer  by wolfram - alpha , so the answer will be the sum of the two condition such that $$\bigg[C(26,1) \times C(25,9) \times P(10,10) \bigg] + C(26,1) \times [x^{10}] \bigg[\bigg( \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ..\bigg) \times \bigg(1+x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ..\bigg)^{25} \bigg] $$

NOTE $2 =$ In my solution  , it is assumed that the particular letter must occur.

Comment: If the particular letter doesn't repeat,  $C(26,1)\times C(25,9)\times P(10,10)$ will overcount by a factor of $10$

Comment: @trueblueanil can you elaborate a little , please ? I cannot see overcounting. First select a particular number and select $9$ random number . Then , arrange them in order by $10!$ . It is the same as first select $10$ number , after that select one of them to be the particular number. Then arrange them in a order

Comment: $\binom{26}{10} = \binom{25}{9}\frac{26}{10}$  , not $26\cdot\binom{25}{9}$.  The non- repeated symbol can be at $10$ spots, whereas you are allowing it to be at $10$ spots in every selection of $9$

Comment: @trueblueanil it has to be at $10$ spots in every selection of $9$ . It is like a key letter as far as i understood by OP's description .If it does not occur , the code cannot run

Comment: **"If** it repeats, we do not know how may times it'll repeat." (Emphasis mine, so it may not repeat or repeat only once)

Comment: @trueblueanil it seems that we have confusion in the meaning of question . I am not a native speaker , but when it is said "may or may not repeated " .I understand what i wrote. Moreover , if it does not occur , then we do not need a particular letter . I thought the particular letter as a part of crypto system .For example , if $k$ does not occur , then it is not a google meeting code according to google crypto algorithm .Because of that reason i think that the particular letter must always occur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128415/discussion-between-bulbasaur-and-true-blue-anil).